# When should I use attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes

I saw some of the examples of utilize attribute, e.g.
(as a map for dynamic factory)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164170.aspx

Just wondering what is the advantage of using attribute?
I can find the reference on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/z0w1kczw(VS.80).aspx
however, I am not sure when and why should I try to use it.

Comment: Whatever you end up deciding to do, keep your attributes as pure data with no behavior. If you need to implement behavior based on the attribute, put the behavior in another class so that you can vary the two independently.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the .NET Framework, attributes can be used for many reasons -- like

- Defining which classes are
  serializable
- Choosing which methods are exposed in
  a Web service

`Attributes` allow us to add `descriptions` to classes, properties, and methods at design time that can then be examined at runtime via reflection.

**Consider this example:**

Say you have a class which has a method from older version which is still in use for any reason and now you have come up with a new version of the class which makes fantastic use of Generic List and LINQ  and has a new method for similar purpose. You would like developers to prefer the new one provided in the later version of your library. How will you do that ? One way is to write in the documentation. A better way is to use attribute as follow.

```
public class AccountsManager
{
  [Obsolete("prefer GetAccountsList", true)]
  static Account[] GetAccounts( ) { }    
  static List<Account> GetAccountsList( ) { }      
}
```

If an `obsolete` method is used when the program is compiled, the developer gets this info and decides accordingly.

> AccountManager.GetAccounts() is obsolete:
>   prefer GetAccountsList

We may also create and add [**`Custom Attributes`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8(VS.80).aspx) as per requirements.

Reference :

- [**Using Attributes in C#**](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/attributes/article.php/c5831)

---

Hope this helps

Comment: Attributes are meta data appended to a class, interface, function, property, etc. in .NET. Metadata provides additional information **about** an item and gives the user of the item the possibility to ackt upon it. Attributes are stored on the Type and not on the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the reference.

Maybe that I am not that good at c# to find a situation that I wish to use customized attribute. I treat attribute as a compiled description. As it requires slow reflection to use, which makes me feel it is not that useful.

Comment: @Obalix your likening of C# attributes to "metadata" was very helpful in improving my understanding. I think that's the best high-level abstract explanation I've ever heard about attributes.

Can you think of a typical situation where use of attributes is absolutely required?

Comment: @Terribad: The use of attributes is "absolutely" required when the metadata provided by them is acted upon by some other code, e.g. WCF data or operation contracts.

Answer (score 31):

My recommendation: use attributes to *state facts about mechanisms*, but not to *model aspects of your business domain*.

More details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/properties-vs-attributes

Comment: Very valuable answer. Thank you Mr. Lippert!

Answer (score 8):

Attributes are appropriate when you want to attach metadata to your classes or class members, as well as when applying a common behaviour without having to implement a certain interface for each unit that shares the behaviour. The latter is an example of [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 4):

Consider an attribute as metadata about the method or property it belongs to. It tells something more about a member.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework predefines and uses attribute types to control run-time behavior of the application.

Consider [webmethod] attribute, at runtime framework resolves this attribute and determine this method going to be exposed in a webservice.

The same way, you can write your custom attributes to control the behaviour of your application at runtime. Attributes can target classes,methods,properties,delegate, enum, event, field...

To resolve the attribute at runtime, you must use reflection.

Checkout the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) link for more details.