# Understanding C# attributes

Tags: c#, attributes

I've been trying to learn about attributes in C#. but can't quite grasp how you use it (and why it's useful).

According to Microsoft's [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) about the subject, apparently attributes adds information about the types in a program (metadata). Been trying to go through their examples, and trying to my own examples, and I still can't grasp the concept.

I would appreciate if someone skilled in C# could walk me through it! I also did see some youtube video's without success.

Below is my example which is faulty, I thought you could somehow all the attribute or use it in some way?

```
using System;

namespace Attributes {

    class SampleAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public int Id { get; set;  }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Sample(Id = 10)]
    class MyClass {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        [Sample(Id = 10)]
        public void Method() {
            Console.WriteLine(Sample.Id);

        }
    }

    internal class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
            myObj.Method();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295119/when-should-i-use-attribute-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are additional metadata, added to type and gives additional information about it. There are a couple of points, where you should use attributes, reflection and serialization are main of them. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295119/when-should-i-use-attribute-in-c) and [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827091/Csharp-Attributes-in-minutes) will help you

Comment: The SO thread you linked to gave me a perfect understanding of the concept. The top 15 pages on google did not, however. 

Thank you!